# Enable multi-machine windows authentication on a home PC with a VM instance?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SSAS instance on my main (home) machine running Win7, *DevPC*. There is no domain. I'd like to enable users on a virtual machine to connect to the SSAS instance on DevPC via windows authentication.

The trouble is that when I go to add users to the role, the only location that shows up is *DevPC*, preventing me from adding users from the virtual machine.

What do I need to do get this setup working?

Answer (score 2):

you need to create the same users and passwords on DevPC that are on the VM (or you can setup an active directory and use a Domain if your machine is windows server but I think repeating the users in this case is a lot easier and work on all windows)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join DevPC to the domain if you want domain users to show up in the list.

Comment: there is no domain

Comment: Ahh, the active-directory tag is misleading then. ;)  laurennt-pnet has the right of things.